# How can node.js local server be limited to a specific baud rate?

Tags: node.js, baud-rate, localserver, bandwidth-throttling

Is there a way to do this?

I'm calling node.js server from a bat file:

```
http-server -p 8080 -c-1
exit
```

I read there is throttle, but there is NO info how it can be used in a command line for node.js server -if at all.